# Evaluate output of OpenSSL before parsing output

Tags: regex, bash, openssl, xargs

Using the following code to check for expiry of SSL certs:

```
cat localdomains | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'openssl s_client -connect $0:443 -servername $0 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | cut -d = -f 2 | xargs -I {} echo {} $0'
```

When I run into domains with no cert returning, I am trying to wrap my head around how to change the output to something like N/A, instead of trying to evaluate "cut -d = -f 2" and then xargs -I

Comment: You have a sample output to check these bunch of commands against? Could be really simplified with a fewer tools used

Comment: you just need a file called localdomains with a list of domains, 1 on each line to check the command

Comment: Find `[ ]*(?:cut|xargs)[ ]+[^|]*` replace with`N/A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you capture the output of your command in a variable you can then validate it.  Assuming this doesn't have to be a one liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read domain; do
  expiry=$(openssl s_client -connect ${domain}:443 -servername ${domain} 2>/dev/null </dev/null | \
    openssl x509 -noout -enddate 2>&1 | cut -d = -f 2)

  # validate output with date
  if date -d "${expiry}" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
    echo ${expiry} ${domain}
  else
    echo "N/A" ${domain}
  fi
done
```

Note a couple of things:

1. Redirect /dev/null into stdin of `openssl s_client` to get the prompt back ([see here for technical details](https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-the-ssl-certificate-from-a-website))
2. Redirect stderr of the second `openssl x509` to stdout in order to validate against it.
3. You could use `grep` or `sed` to validate the output.  I found `date` to be convenient (and if you wanted to use it to reformat the date, it would be extra-convenient).

I tested this solution by putting it into a file `check_cert_expiry.sh`:

```
$ cat localdomains 
stackoverflow.com
example.example
google.com
$ cat localdomains | ./check_cert_expiry.sh 
Aug 14 12:00:00 2019 GMT stackoverflow.com
N/A example.example
Feb 21 09:37:00 2018 GMT google.com
```

Cheers!